# Index ID bigger than bigint in sphinxsearch

Tags: sphinx

How can I have an `ID` field bigger than a `bigint` in sphinxsearch?

That is to say, larger than `9,223,372,036,854,775,807 * 2 + 1`?

Is it possible to fuse two ID columns as one?

Comment: why do you need such a large ID? 2^64 is such a large number that if you write 1 billion IDs to memory a second then it would take nearly 600 years to complete

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fuse two ID columns as one?

No.

Need to figure out a solution to get a single 64bit number. Perhaps using hashing?